# Reportlab no es reconocido

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

estoy tratando de crear un pdf con reporlab. el código es muy simple, sin embargo siempre me da este error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab.pdfgen'; 'reportlab'
> is not a package

Aquí dejo el código:

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

c = canvas.Canvas("ticket.pdf", pagesize=A4)
c.drawString(100,750,"Empresa")
c.setTitle("Ticket")

c.save()
```

Edit: intenté re instalar la librería y borrarla y volverla a instalar. No funcionó